# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool DataSourceFactory

Tags: tomcat, datasource, tomcat6, jndi, connection-pooling

I'm investigating moving away from an Oracle connection pool and using the Tomcat connection pool. I followed the myriad of example for configuring the `<Resource>` in Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml`. I found great info [here](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html). However, when I start Tomcat, I get the following error:

> javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool DataSourceFactory]

I'm using Tomcat 6.0. My `<Resource>` config in `/conf/server.xml` is:

```xml
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/myds"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    auth="Container" 
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.33:1234:myds"
    user="myuname"
    password="mypasswd"
/>
```

I understand that Tomcat can't find the factory class, but I don't understand **why**? I don't see anything in the documentation about adding extra `.jar` files. I've looked in the distribution and can't find the golden `.jar` anyway.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Tomcat JDBC pool was [introduced](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) in Tomcat 7.0.19, yet you're attempting to use it in Tomcat 6.0 without any further configuration.

For Tomcat 6.0 you need to manually [download](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/) and drop the latest release of the `tomcat-jdbc.jar` file in `/lib` folder of the Tomcat installation.