# run the .jar app in server error

Tags: java, jar

im trying to deploy an app in tomcat6 on centos5, but the problem is the app will not start
i have a log in "usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.out"
the last lines which are about starting the app are

```
Mar 1, 2013 10:24:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener
addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException:
Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]
Mar 1, 2013 10:24:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 1, 2013 10:24:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled for

```
Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory
```

and got this, which sounds very promising: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool DataSourceFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723830/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-tomcat-jdbc-pool-datasourcefactory)

Comment: yep, i did this before but still wont start, i have new errors

Comment: 'new errors' can be an improvement, because something is correct now, but not everything, or it isn't an improvement, because everything got worse. Depends on the 'new errors'.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that inside your tomcat installation folder you have a lib folder containing the file
tomcat-dbcp.jar

Inside your context.xml file you should have something like this:

```
<Context path="/YourApp"> 
 <Resource username="dbUser" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName" 
     type="javax.sql.DataSource" removeAbandonedTimeout="120" removeAbandoned="true" 
     password="******" name="jdbc/dbName" 
     driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" autoReconnect="true" auth="Container"/> 
 </Context>
```

Comment: my context is exactly the same, but it will not start

Comment: Other apps without connection pools start?  Post your code to get a Connection object in your Servlet.