# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory

Tags: jdbc, tomcat7

Tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724057/932307) by copying the [file](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/) to `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` and also to `/usr/share/java` still getting the error

> javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class
>   [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]

Appreciate some help.