# IntelliJ Struts 2 application startup problems

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jdbc, struts2

I'm trying to create a struts2 application. I've set up the spring, struts and web xml files. When I leave out the filter "StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter", it deploys to the tomcat server, but when I go to a jsp, with any type of struts tag in it, I get the following error.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [An

exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 259



Stacktrace:] with root cause
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005furl_005f0(index_jsp.java:638)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Then when I put the filter back in my web.xml file, the server doesn't even deploy. When I restart the server with the filter, I get this:

```
Connected to server
[2015-07-29 07:55:21,077] Artifact Admin:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManagerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jul 29, 2015 7:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jul 29, 2015 7:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 29, 2015 7:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2015-07-29 07:55:27,837] Artifact Admin:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Jul 29, 2015 7:55:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/manager
Jul 29, 2015 7:55:31 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue$FairIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue.iterator(FairBlockingQueue.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:989)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:981)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.run(ConnectionPool.java:1348)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Exception in thread "PoolCleaner[2142566374:1438221326908]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/FairBlockingQueue$FairIterator
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue.iterator(FairBlockingQueue.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:989)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkIdle(ConnectionPool.java:981)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.run(ConnectionPool.java:1348)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.FairBlockingQueue$FairIterator
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

  <!--Spring Configuration -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring.xml,</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.howe.listener.InitContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>xssFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.howe.Filter.XssFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>xssFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>xssFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.howe.Action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>504</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Could someone plase help me? Could it be the versions of the jars in my project?

Here's my lib folder:

[image: HERE IS PART OF MY LIB FOLDER]

[image: PART 2 OF MY LIB FOLDER]

[image: PART 3 OF MY LIB FOLDER]

Comment: Show your web.xml and your lib folder

Comment: I have added what you requested

Comment: Did you try hiding `XSSFilter ` configuration in `web.xml` ?

Comment: A lot of libraries are not from Struts. If you are using Struts and have problems with it make sure you have all required dependencies. *Don't* copy server libraries to the application, instead use runtime scope for the server dependencies.

Comment: Babel was right.... The xssFilter had some dependencies that I forgot to add, and on startup when the constructor ran it couldn't create the class. The logs were a little misleading but I figured it out! Thanks guys.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724057/1654265), Tomcat JDBC pool has been introduced in Tomcat 7.0.19.

Since you've not specified which Tomcat version you're using, then

- **if Tomcat `< 7.0.19`**: you need to put the `tomcat-jdbc.jar` in Tomcat shared `/lib` folder, not in your ear/war lib folder like you are doing;
- **if Tomcat `>= 7.0.19`**, the jar is already on the server, and you are getting the NoClassDefFoundError because you are putting it in the ear/war and Tomcat doesn't know which one to pick (between the server one and the package one).

In both cases, **you need to remove it from your package**.

In Maven you do it by adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to your dependencies already on the server.

Comment: Also remember to paste code (not images) in your questions, and consider upgrading to 2.3.24 instead of staying with 2.3.16.2. Newer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Babel was right.... The xssFilter had some dependencies that I forgot to add, and on startup when the constructor ran it couldn't create the class. The logs were a little misleading but I figured it out! Thanks guys